# Difference of 00:00 (24:00) and 23:00 (23:00)

Tags: sql-server, database, difference

How to get the difference of 00:00 (24:00) and 23:00 (23:00) using MS SQL?

Example:
(End Time) 00:00 - (Start Time) 23:30 = 1,410. 
But it should be = 0.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATEDIFF does not guarantee that the full number of the specified time units passed between 2 datetime values:

-- Get difference in hours between 8:55 and 11:00 SELECT DATEDIFF(hh, '08:55', '11:00'); -- Returns 3 although only 2 hours and 5 minutes passed between times   -- Get difference in months between Sep 30, 2011 and Nov 02, 2011 SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, '2011-09-30', '2011-11-02') -- Returns 2 although only 1 month and 2 days passed between dates

To get the number of full time units passed between datetimes, you can calculate the difference in lower units and then divide by the appropriate number:

SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, '08:55', '11:00')/60; -- Returns 2 hours now

http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server/functions/datediff

Comment: I tried this query

'SELECT DATEDIFF (mi,'23:00','00:00')/60

'however output is -23 where it should be 1.

just need to find the difference of 00:00 (which is 24:00)  - 23:00 = 1

Comment: ok, was able to figure this out using SELECT DATEDIFF CAST, thanks guys for the help